# Add date stamp when new row added by Zapier

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, zapier

I am trying to add a submission date to column 1 whenever a new row is automatically added through Zapier. Is this possible? E.g.,

```
 C1                              C2              C3
 (DATE STAMP WHEN SUBMITTED)     John            Smith
 (DATE STAMP WHEN SUBMITTED)     Sam             Hardy
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include the time your Zap runs in your Zap (or use that as an approximation of when the trigger occurs), you can use the following field in your Zap: {{zap_meta_human_now}}

Just enter that text with the curly braces into the field instead of selecting something from the dropdown.

For more information, see: https://zapier.com/help/advanced-tips/#time-stamps

Comment: Wonderful! Didn't know these existed. Thanks @Kurt!

Answer (score 1):

I think this requires a script (Tools > Script Editor), such as the following: it checks for blank A cells where there is data in B, and puts today's date there. If you use it, be sure to change the timezone ("GMT" in the example) to yours ([here's a list of timezone names](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html)).

One way to have this  run is to add a trigger (Resources > Current project's triggers in the script editor) that will execute this "on change".

```
function fillDate() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sh.getRange("A2:B");       // assuming A is the date column
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (!values[i][0] && values[i][1]) {
      range.getCell(i+1, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    }
  }
}
```