# Automatic insertion of current date when rows are entered via Zapier

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, zapier

Unfortunately, as a new user I am not allowed to comment. This is why I need to do a new post regarding to this topic: [Insert current date to cell based on content in other cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88502/insert-current-date-to-cell-based-on-content-in-other-cell/88510#88510)

This is my code in Google Sheets Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == 'Tabellenblatt1' && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

It works perfectly when I enter data in cell 1 manually, but when data is added via API (in this case when data is added via Zapier) it does not work.
Anybody can give me a hint why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit triggers, simple and installable, are triggered by changes directly done by the user while having the spreadsheet open in a web browser.

Similar Q&A

- [Trigger function when IMPORTRANGE() is updated](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104025/88163)

Reference

- [Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Comment: Hey Rubén, thanks for your answer! That sounds logical to me. Is there an alternative way to achieve this task? Thanks, Flo

Comment: @FloIceing Have you seeing [Add date stamp when new row added by Zapier](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/81150/88163)?

Comment: @FloIceing Please checkout [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)